# JQuery Ajax returning bool(false)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've been looking at other questions related to my problem however none seem to correspond to my exact circumstances. I'm attempting to create a javascript variable which I will POST with Ajax to a PHP variable further down in my code. After hopefully setting the variable correctly I attempt to POST and var_dump the result however it is not the "0" I had hoped for but rather a frustrating bool(false). I've read that this may be a problem with the url (as I POST from the same file) or perhaps some other issue to do with the transfer of data to the Ajax request though I have as yet been unable to work out the issue. Testing for the data in the console also shows nothing so I've been forced to ask here. Thank you for any help or guidance.

**Javascript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){var offset = parseInt("0");
        $.ajax({url: 'index.php', type: 'POST', data: offset, success:function(data){return data;}});
    });
```

**PHP**

```
<?php var_dump(isset($_POST['offset']));
```

Comment: did you tried with dataType: 'text' ?

Comment: yep! everything returns the same bool(false) response I'm afraid

Comment: Convert your offset to string `'0'` then change it on server side.

Comment: @aldrin27 How exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) in your php.
That *literally* returns the string: `"bool(true)"`.

Use [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php), instead.

[Instead of](http://www.tehplayground.com/#ZY1arXwWl):

```
<?php var_dump(isset($_POST['offset'])); ?>
```

[Use](http://www.tehplayground.com/#la3e2Q2MV):

```
<?php var_export(isset($_POST['offset'])); ?>
```

`var_export` will output the string representation of the value, instead of the type / value combo `var_dump` returns.

---

If you just want to return the posted value, do this:

```
<?php var_export($_POST['offset']); ?>
```

Or:

```
<?php echo json_encode($_POST['offset']); ?>
```

---

Just keep in mind that you need to pass the data to the `post`, correctly:

```
data: { offset: offset }
```

Instead of:

```
data: offset
```

Comment: Let me tell you I am having a hell of a time testing all of these options. This now returns `false`

Comment: What _do_ you want to get returned, then?  Looking at your php, you want to return a boolean that says whether or not `$_POST['offset']` is set.

Comment: Ah well that would be the problem. I'm simply trying to send "0" as an integer, my mistake.

Comment: As OP said: "however it is not the "0" I had hoped for but rather a frustrating bool(false)". @Cerbrus, try my answer.

Comment: ReneKorss: That would mean the OP literally wants returned what he's sending to the php. @masteryupa: What exactly do you want returned from the server?

Comment: Sorry I think I've confused people with my phrasing, I should be clear. I simply want to do what @Cerbrus has said and return what I've sent to the php which would be "0". Sorry for the confusion, it's been a long day.

Comment: @masteryupa: Updated my answer.

Comment: Ah excellent thank you, this is now returning null so we have at least made some progress.

Comment: Right. Now all you need to do is properly pass the data to the php call, as mentioned in other answers: `data: { offset: offset }`

Comment: @Cerbrus It's telling me that there is an undefined index: offset and still returning null, is there something more I should be including?

Comment: Hm, that's weird. No idea why that error is showing.

Comment: Var_export does the same thing so I'm not sure either but you've been a tremendous help anyway so thank you.

Answer (score 3):

add an `index` called `offfest`

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php', 
    type: 'POST', 
    data: {offset:offset}, 
    success:function(data){
        return data;
    }
});
```

Comment: This was how I had set up the request earlier (changed it just to see if trying anything different would work). Giving a shot now hasn't changed anything though so I think there is something else going on.

Comment: hmm.  are there any console errors? and can you see the request being sent to the server?

Answer (score 3):

you can try with :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({url: 'index.php', type: 'POST', data: {offset: parseInt("0")}, success:function(data){return data;}});
});
```

Comment: I feel like your answer should definitely work but it just returns the same answer. There's got to be something else going on in the background that I'm not aware of. Thank you though, this was very useful

Answer (score 2):

I'm not totally familiar with PHP but in your javascript code, data should be dictionary for Ajax post. something like {'offset': 0}

Answer (score 1):

Js:

```
var offset = parseInt("0");
$.ajax({url: 'index.php', type: 'POST', data:{offset: offset},success:function(data){alert(data.offset);}});
```

php:

```
<?php echo json_encode(array('offset'=>isset($_POST['offset'])));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Am now receiving this error
`Notice: Use of undefined constant offset - assumed 'offset' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/parable/index.php on line 149
{"offset":false}`

Comment: Thank you. Now simply `{"offset":false}`

Answer (score 0):

you should give a name to the offset variable
so , change your data parameter into a JSON format :

```
$.ajax({url: 'index.php', type: 'POST', data:{ 'offset': offset},success:function(data){return data;}});
```